# Setting Word Drop-down boxes through Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I have a Word document that I am trying to fill out programmatically through Access.  The drop downs are Content Controls in Word.  I am able to set all but one drop down and I cant see any difference in the Word document that would be a problem.

The code looks like:

```
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim objCC As ContentControl
Dim objCE As ContentControlListEntry
Dim ListSelection As String

Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
WordApp.Documents.Add Template:=strTemplateLocation, newtemplate:=False

With WordApp

  ListSelection = Me.cmbAvailability.ListIndex + 2
  Set objCC = .ActiveDocument.ContentControls(5): Set objCE = objCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(ListSelection): objCE.Select

  ListSelection = Me.Area.ListIndex + 2
  Set objCC = .ActiveDocument.ContentControls(13): Set objCE = objCC.DropdownListEntries.Item(ListSelection): objCE.Select
```

**There are about a dozen drop downs set here, just included a couple.  The fisrt set line works, but the second ("Area") doesn't.  In the full code, there are several drop down set before and after the "Area" line executes, all the others work.  I double checked to be sure the contentcontrol ID is correct.  I am sure I am just missing something, but cant see it.  Any ideas or suggestions on what to look at?

Comment: `I have a Word document that I am trying to fill out programmatically through Access.` dear God I'm so sorry. Do you have a patreon? I'll send money.  Your poor family... I'm crying right now.  This is terrible.  Nobody should have to face this.  Nobody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, right after posting I found the problem.  Someone had typed in the selection in Access and it didn't match the dropdown.  I just needed to lock the users from typing in a response and force the use of the drop downs.